# Must ANTLR Visitor classes override all methods in the base class for grammar rules?

Tags: c#, parsing, antlr4

I am trying to trace the execution path of an ANTLR visitor implementation as execution flows from the user program to my overridden visitor class (MyHelloVisitor) which inherits from the base class (HelloBaseVisitor).

As far as I can tell, the override class (MyHelloVisitor) *must* contain an override method for at least the top-level grammar rule (named 'toprule' in my grammar).

Q1. Must the override class (MyHelloVisitor) always contain an override method for the starting rule of the grammar?

Q2. Must the override class (MyHelloVisitor) always contain an override method for *each* rule in the grammar and base class? Or is it possible for me to just override a single method of interest?
Thank you.

Here is code for the user program that calls MyHelloVisitor (my overriding Visitor class):

```
  // create a visitor and walk the parse tree, collecting errors or results
  var visitor = new MyHelloVisitor(); // inherits generic abstract n virtual methods
  var ctx = Parser.toprule(); // this returns a context for the top rule
  visitor.Visit(ctx);
```

When the .Visit method from the base class (shown below) is executed *by* MyHelloVisitor, the cast operation succeeds and the .VisitToprule method is called. That is why I think the overriding class (MyHelloVisitor) *must* contain at least an override method for the 'Toprule' in the grammar.

```
    public virtual Result Visit([NotNull] IParseTree tree) =>    
     tree.Accept<Result>((IParseTreeVisitor<Result>) this);
      ....


    public partial class TopruleContext : ParserRuleContext {
        public override TResult Accept<TResult>(IParseTreeVisitor<TResult> visitor) {
            IHelloVisitor<TResult> typedVisitor = visitor as IHelloVisitor<TResult>;
            if (typedVisitor != null) return typedVisitor.VisitToprule(this);
            else return visitor.VisitChildren(this);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q1. Must the override class (MyHelloVisitor) always contain an override method for the starting rule of the grammar?

No, you can have an empty custom visitor that extends the (generated) base visitor. Also note that there is no practical difference between a start-rule (often the first rule in the grammar and/or a parser rule that ends with `EOF`) and another parser rule in a grammar.

> Q2. Must the override class (MyHelloVisitor) always contain an override method for each rule in the grammar and base class? Or is it possible for me to just override a single method of interest?

No, you don't need to override each rule. However, a visitor is often used to make a complete traversal of the parse tree and return something. This would generally mean all visit-methods have a custom implementation. If you selectively want to "listen" for events like entering or exiting a specific parser rule/node, then a listener might be what you're after: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/listeners.md

Comment: Thank you! Your answer implied that if my goal was to do a complete traversal (it is), then I would need a complete set of custom override methods for each rule in the grammar, and each overridden method would be responsible for explicitly visiting its children. Is that correct? (I have trouble visualizing how the default VisitChildren call in the base class (`if (typedVisitor != null)...`) would get triggered if I'm always passing in my MyHelloVisitor class as the visitor).

Comment: After even more study, I think I conclude that this code `if (typedVisitor != null) return typedVisitor.VisitToprule(this);`, even if it calls my typed visitor `MyHelloVisitor.VisitToprule`, will nonetheless execute the default base class method for `VisitToprule` if there is no custom implementation of `VisitToprule` in the `MyHelloVisitor` class. Is that conclusion correct? (If it was, it answers my dilemma.) Thank you.

Comment: Thank you again!